# e.slice is not a function in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have a asp.net application where i have kendo ui treeview in aspx page. on document ready, i am calling a method in the aspx page for the data. The kendo treeview is not loading the data dynamically. It only shows the loading indicator. When we provide the same json data in aspx page itself, it works fine.

Here is the code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string MakeTreeData()
{
   return "[{ text: \"Node1\", items: [{text:\"Child1\"},{text:\"Child2\"},{text:\"Child3\"}]}]";
}
```

**script**

```
var $jQuery2_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$jQuery2_1(document).ready(function () {
        $jQuery2_1.ajax({ url: "Default.aspx/MakeTreeData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "post",
            success: function (result) {
                var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                    data: JSON.parse(result.d),
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            children: "items"
                        }
                    }
                });
                $jQuery2_1("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    dataSource: viewModel,
                    dataTextField: "text"
                });
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's `e.slice` appearing in your code?

Comment: @Alex When i set the viewmodel to datasource, the javascript error appears.
$jQuery2_1("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    dataSource: viewModel,
                    dataTextField: "text"
                });

Answer (score 0):

Updating the method and script like below solved the issue

**MakeTreeData**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string MakeTreeData()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var parentNodes = new List<Node>();
    var parent = new Node() { Id = "1", Text = "Parent 1", Nodes = new List<Node>() };
    var child = new Node() { Id = "2", Text = "Child 1", Nodes = new List<Node>() };
    parent.Nodes.Add(child);
    parentNodes.Add(parent);
    return js.Serialize(parentNodes);
}
```

**Script**

```
<div class="demo-section k-content">
    <div id="treeview"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/MakeTreeData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.d);
                var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                    data: JSON.parse(result.d),
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            children: "Nodes"
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    dataSource: viewModel,
                    dataTextField: "Text"
                });
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```